# SharePoint 2010 having user profile without starting user profile service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

We have installed SharePoint 2010 in our environment. When I go user profile service to configure Synchronization, all the user profile already imported into SharePoint without user profile service configuration!

Can anyone let me know reason behind this automatically import of user profile without user profile service configuration?

Comment: Did you use any of the setup wizards?

Comment: +1 on the Farm Configuration Wizard. You still need to configure the import manually, unless you have already let users start using the environment. They will have profiles created for them.

Comment: @Brian: No. We have not used any setup wizards except SharePoint Configuration Wizard.

Comment: Have your users manually created profiles by visiting MySites or their profile page?

Comment: No. They have not created their profile manually